# How to get all the gas value in % from gas sensor MQ135

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, arduino-uno

How to get all the gas value (of co2, nh3, alcohol, smoke, benzene)  in % from gas sensor MQ135 . i am using raspberry pi 3 and arduino.. thanks

Comment: Please see my amended answer after reading the datasheet carefully.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is not possible.  This particular sensor does not report readings of individual gases and pollutants.  It reports a value that represents air quality.  Read the datasheet for your part if you want to understand what it reports if calibrated properly.

If you're working with a naked sensor (no breakout board or printed circuit board and just have a sensor), then do this:

Read the datasheet for the part to see the wiring diagram.  That way this picture will make more sense:
[image: wiring diagram]

Then code your sketch as follows:

```
int value;
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);      // sets the serial port to 9600
}

void loop()
{
  sensorvalue = analogRead(sensorPin);   
  Serial.println(value, DEC);  // print decimal value
  delay(100);                  // wait at least 100 milliseconds 
}
```

Comment: @SonuGadewar if you found my answer useful, please "Accept" it so that others might find it easier in the future.